# Want to replace certain rows in one dataframe with rows from another based on matching timestamps (both dataframes have timestamps in the same tz)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to be able to take some values from one dataframe and have these inserted into another dataframe (both have the same amount of columns with the same titles)

I want the values in each row from dataframe 1 to replace those in dataframe 2 based on a matching timestamps.

For most of the rows/timestamps I want the original data to remain in dataframe 1 so this is only for a set of specific timestamps (those in dataframe 2)

Does dplyr solve this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

It may be more easier in `data.table` with a join.  Get the column names of the first dataset except the 'timestamp' column ('nm1' - Note that here we assume column names to be same), join `on` by the 'timestamp' column and assign the corresponding columns (`i.`) from the second dataset when it matches the 'timestamp' column

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), "timestamp")
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := mget(nm2), on = .(timestamp)]
```

Comment: I agree - joining by timestamp is a huge part of my regular data management and data table is king.  I have whole scripts dedicated to it.  I would suggest adding roll = "nearest" and mult = "first" to the join for when your timestamps are not exact.  then add a difftime column to evaluate the offset.

Comment: @DanSlone yes, you are right. Unfortunately, most people posting on SO doesn't consider giving any examples which makes it difficult to understand exactly the problem